# Extracting an element using SimpleXMLElement

Tags: php, simplexml

I have been trying to get the SimpleXMLElement to extract a vsingle value fro an XML file using the following code per php.net examples:

```
$resp = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
foreach($resp->SESSION_LIST->SESSION as $sess){
    $type = $sess->TRACKING->TYPE;
}
```

When I do so, the return value is always another simpleXML Object, and I am stuck as to how to get just the value I am looking for. Can someone please give me a push in the right direction?

Here is the XML string I am using. It can have multiple SESSION attributes:

```
$xml = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <FREIGHTVIEW>
        <SESSION_LIST>
            <SESSION id="529075">
                <SESSION_ID>529075</SESSION_ID>
                <LABEL>116800</LABEL>
                <INTEGRATION_REFERENCE_NUMBER>WDLSTRFDTS</INTEGRATION_REFERENCE_NUMBER>
                <TRACKING>
                <TYPE>provider assigned</TYPE> 
                <EVENT_DATETIME>03/01/11 02:07:59 PM</EVENT_DATETIME> 
                <TIMEZONE /> 
                <USER_NAME>Dispatch Team</USER_NAME> 
                <COMPANY_NAME>M&amp;W Distribution</COMPANY_NAME> 
                <RECORDED_DATETIME>03/01/11 02:07:59 PM</RECORDED_DATETIME> 
                <SOURCE /> 
            </TRACKING> 
            <QUOTE id="5173468"> 
                <QUOTE_ID>5173468</QUOTE_ID> 
                <CARRIER type="Private"> 
                    <NAME>- FedEx Freight Priority -</NAME> 
                    <CARRIER_REFERENCE_NUMBER>FXFE</CARRIER_REFERENCE_NUMBER> 
                    <CONTACT>- FedEx Freight Priority -</CONTACT> 
                    <EMAIL /> 
                    <PHONE></PHONE> 
                </CARRIER> 
                <TOTAL_AMOUNT>262.57</TOTAL_AMOUNT> 
                <ACCESSORIALS> 
                    <ACCESSORIAL> 
                        <NAME>fuel surcharge</NAME> 
                        <AMOUNT>79.47</AMOUNT> 
                    </ACCESSORIAL>
                    <ACCESSORIAL> 
                        <NAME>delivery appointment request</NAME> 
                        <AMOUNT>0.00</AMOUNT> 
                    </ACCESSORIAL> 
                    <ACCESSORIAL> 
                        <NAME>line haul</NAME> 
                        <AMOUNT>183.10</AMOUNT> 
                    </ACCESSORIAL> 
                </ACCESSORIALS> 
                <EQUIPMENT> 
                    <MODE>ltl</MODE> 
                    <TYPE></TYPE> 
                </EQUIPMENT> 
                <PICKUP_DATE></PICKUP_DATE> 
                <ESTIMATED_DELIVERY_DATE></ESTIMATED_DELIVERY_DATE> 
                <REFERENCE_ID>37307086</REFERENCE_ID> 
                <QUOTE_GOOD_UNTIL></QUOTE_GOOD_UNTIL> 
                <QUOTE_TYPE>instant ltl</QUOTE_TYPE> 
                <COMMENTS></COMMENTS> 
                <QUOTE_STATUS>assigned</QUOTE_STATUS> 
            </QUOTE> 
        </SESSION> 
    </SESSION_LIST> 
</FREIGHTVIEW>
XML;
```

Comment: You know what would be ***really** freaking useful here... telling us which element you actually want.

Comment: SESSION elements, not attributes. :)

Comment: I do apologize for not clarifying "which freaking element I actually want", it is the value within the <TYPE> element. I thought that would have been clear from the example. I will ensure to be very specific next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to typecast the object to a string:

```
$type = (string) $sess->TRACKING->TYPE;
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I was tearing hair out over it. The [PHP documentation](http://ie2.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) never mentions it, which iss unusual. PHP documentation is usually pretty good.

Comment: I've actually reported this as a bug in the PHP documentation.